# Non-standard subsetting of data.frames

Tags: r, evaluation

One of the quirks of subsetting a data frame is that you have to repeatedly type the name of that data frame when mentioning columns. For example, the data frame `cars` is mentioned 3 times here:

```
cars[cars$speed == 4 & cars$dist < 10, ]
##   speed dist
## 1     4    2
```

The `data.table` package solves this.

```
library(data.table)
dt_cars <- as.data.table(cars)
dt_cars[speed == 4 & dist < 10]
```

As does `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
cars %>% filter(speed == 4, dist < 10)
```

I'd like to know if a solution exists for standard-issue data.frames (that is, not resorting to `data.table` or `dplyr`).

I think I'm looking for something like

```
cars[MAGIC(speed == 4 & dist < 10), ]
```

or

```
MAGIC(cars[speed == 4 & dist < 10, ])
```

where `MAGIC` is to be determined.

I tried the following, but it gave me an error.

```
library(rlang)
cars[locally(speed == 4 & dist < 10), ]
# Error in locally(speed == 4 & dist < 10) : object 'speed' not found
```

Comment: How about `with(cars, 
 cars[speed == 4 & dist < 10, ])`

Comment: @G5W `with()` needs the data frame name twice. As does `cars[eval(substitute(speed == 4 & dist < 10, cars)), ]`.

Comment: dplyr works on standard data.frames

Comment: Isn't  `subset` the answer?

Comment: @BrodieG Yes `subset()` solves it. I was more interested in seeing if there is a way to do it with `[`.

Comment: @BrodieG It seems like there was a lot of effort recently around thinking about evaluation of tidyverse code, and I wondered if you could separate the evaluation part from the tidyverse part.

Comment: As far as I can tell there isn't a way to do this without referencing the symbol twice (once as the environment, once as the object to subset), other than with subset/data.table/dplyr.  Would be curious if someone came up with something (attach doesn't count).

Comment: fun fact: this was the original purpose of `data.table`! https://mobile.twitter.com/MattDowle/status/717152933410775040

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) subset** This only requires that `cars` be mentioned once. No packages are used.

```
subset(cars, speed == 4 & dist < 10)
##   speed dist
## 1     4    2
```

**2) sqldf** This uses a package but does not use dplyr or data.table which were the only two packages excluded by the question:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * from cars where speed = 4 and dist < 10")
##   speed dist
## 1     4    2
```

**3) assignment**  Not sure if this counts but you could assign `cars` to some other variable name such as `.` and then use that.  In that case `cars` would only be mentioned once.  This uses no packages.

```
. <- cars
.[.$speed == 4 & .$dist < 10, ]
##   speed dist
## 1     4    2
```

or

```
. <- cars
with(., .[speed == 4 & dist < 10, ])
##   speed dist
## 1     4    2
```

With respect to these two solutions you might want to check out this article on the Bizarro Pipe: http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2017/01/using-the-bizarro-pipe-to-debug-magrittr-pipelines-in-r/

**4) magrittr** This could also be expressed in magrittr and that package was not excluded by the question.  Note we are using the magrittr `%$%` operator:

```
library(magrittr)

cars %$% .[speed == 4 & dist < 10, ]
##   speed dist
## 1     4    2
```

Answer (score 3):

`subset` is the base function which solves this problem. However, like all base R functions which use non-standard evaluation `subset` does not perform fully hygienic code expansion. So `subset()` evaluates the wrong variable when used within non-global scopes (such as in lapply loops).

As an example, here we define the variable `var` in two places, first in the global scope with value `40`, then in a local scope with value `30`. The use of `local()` here is for simplicity, however this would behave equivalently inside a function. Intuitively, we would expect `subset` to use the value `30` in the evaluation. However upon executing the following code we see instead the value `40` is used (so no rows are returned).

```
var <- 40

local({
  var <- 30
  dfs <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
  lapply(dfs, subset, mpg > var)
})

#> [[1]]
#>  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

This happens because the `parent.frame()` used in `subset()` is the environment within the body of `lapply()` rather than the local block. Because all environments eventually inherit from the global environment the variable `var` is found there with value `40`.

Hygienic variable expansion via quasiquotation (as implemented in the [rlang package](http://rlang.tidyverse.org/)) solves this problem. We can define a variant of subset using tidy evaluation that works properly in all contexts. The code is derived from and largely identical to that of `base::subset.data.frame()`.

```
subset2 <- function (x, subset, select, drop = FALSE, ...) {
  r <- if (missing(subset))
    rep_len(TRUE, nrow(x))
  else {
    r <- rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::enquo(subset), x)
    if (!is.logical(r))
      stop("'subset' must be logical")
    r & !is.na(r)
  }
  vars <- if (missing(select))
    TRUE
  else {
    nl <- as.list(seq_along(x))
    names(nl) <- names(x)
    rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::enquo(select), nl)
  }
  x[r, vars, drop = drop]
}
```

This version of subset behaves identically to `base::subset.data.frame()`.

```
subset2(mtcars, gear > 4, disp:wt)
#>                 disp  hp drat    wt
#> Porsche 914-2  120.3  91 4.43 2.140
#> Lotus Europa    95.1 113 3.77 1.513
#> Ford Pantera L 351.0 264 4.22 3.170
#> Ferrari Dino   145.0 175 3.62 2.770
#> Maserati Bora  301.0 335 3.54 3.570
```

However `subset2()` does not suffer the scoping issues of subset. In our previous example the value `30` is used for `var`, as we would expect from lexical scoping rules.

```
local({
  var <- 30
  dfs <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
  lapply(dfs, subset2, mpg > var)
})

#> [[1]]
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

This allows non-standard evaluation to be used robustly in all contexts, not just in top level contexts as with previous approaches.

This makes functions which use non-standard evaluation much more useful. Before while they were nice to have for interactive use, you needed to use more verbose standard evaluation functions when writing functions and packages. Now the same function can be used in all contexts without needing to modify the code!

For more details on non-standard evaluation please see Lionel Henry's [Tidy evaluation (hygienic fexprs) presentation](https://www.r-project.org/dsc/2017/slides/tidyeval-hygienic-fexprs.pdf), the [rlang vignette on tidy evaluation](http://rlang.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-evaluation.html) and the [programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette.

Answer (score 2):

I understand I'm totally cheating, but technically it works :):

```
with(cars, data.frame(speed=speed,dist=dist)[speed == 4 & dist < 10,])
#   speed dist
# 1     4    2
```

More horror:

```
`[` <- function(x,i,j){
  rm(`[`,envir = parent.frame())
  eval(parse(text=paste0("with(x,x[",deparse(substitute(i)),",])")))
  }
cars[speed == 4 & dist < 10, ]

#   speed dist
# 1     4    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with overriding `[` method for data.frame. In the new method we check class of the `i` argument and if it is expression or formula we evaluate it in the data.frame context.

```
##### override subsetting method
`[.data.frame` = function (x, i, j, ...) {
    if(!missing(i) && (is.language(i) || is.symbol(i) || inherits(i, "formula"))) {
        if(inherits(i, "formula")) i = as.list(i)[[2]] 
        i = eval(i, x, enclos = baseenv())
    } 
    base::`[.data.frame`(x, i, j, ...)
}

#####

data(cars)
cars[cars$speed == 4 & cars$dist < 10, ]
#     speed dist
# 1     4    2

# cars[speed == 4 & dist < 10, ] # error

cars[quote(speed == 4 & dist < 10),] 
#     speed dist
# 1     4    2


# ,or
cars[~ speed == 4 & dist < 10,]
#     speed dist
# 1     4    2
```

Another solution with more magic. Please, restart R session to avoid interference with previous solution:

```
locally = function(expr){
    curr_call = as.list(sys.call(1))
    if(as.character(curr_call[[1]])=="["){
        possibly_df = eval(curr_call[[2]], parent.frame())
        if(is.data.frame(possibly_df)){
            expr = substitute(expr)
            expr = eval(expr, possibly_df, enclos = baseenv())
        }
    }
    expr
}

cars[locally(speed == 4 & dist < 10), ]
#     speed dist
# 1     4    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `attach()`

```
attach(cars)
cars[speed == 4 & dist < 10,]
#   speed dist
# 1     4    2
```

I was very early on in my R learning dissuaded from using `attach()`, but as long as you're careful not to introduce name conflicts I think it should be OK.

Comment: You are absolutely right of course, but it feels rather wrong to upvote an answer suggesting attach.

Comment: Yeah, it's still not an approach I would endorse. It gives me a slight icky feeling thinking about it.

Comment: anyway it's still mentionned twice, so you might as well use `with(cars, cars[speed == 4 & dist < 10, ])`. not to mention you still need a call to detach.